# KeyError when removing a given node within a dictionary that uses a set, Dijkstra Shortest Path Algorithim

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set, dijkstra

apologies if there is any unnoticed mistakes within my code I don't have great experience with python, however, have been working on a networks assignment throughout the weekend and have been quite stumped with successfully removing a node completely without any problems.

If I could get any suggestions or solutions of where I'm going wrong and how to fix it I'd appreciate it. If any more information is needed I'll provide the best I can. I'm open to any changes that may be more effective in different areas of the code too.

I am supposed to remove a node completely which is essentially declaring a router as dead and eliminating the connection

Problem area:

```
class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph_edges = []
        self.nodes = set()
        self.adjacency_list = {}

    def add_edge(self, frm, to, cost=0):
        self.graph_edges.append((frm, to, float(cost)))

        for edge in self.graph_edges:
            self.nodes.update([edge[0], edge[1]])

        self.adjacency_list = {node: set() for node in self.nodes}
        for edge in self.graph_edges:
            self.adjacency_list[edge[0]].add((edge[1], edge[2]))

    def remove_edge(self, node):
        if node in self.nodes:
            self.nodes.remove(node)
            #print(self.nodes)
        for nodeval in self.adjacency_list.copy():
            if node in self.adjacency_list:
                print(self.adjacency_list.values())
                del self.adjacency_list[node]
                #print(self.adjacency_list) 
        for check in self.graph_edges.copy():
            if node in list(check):
                self.graph_edges.remove(check)
                #print(ch)
        for k,v in self.adjacency_list.items(): # I'm assuming the problem is within here
            for a in v:
                if node == a[0]:
                    del self.adjacency_list[node]
                    #print(self.adjacency_list[node])
```

Here is how the output should work:

```
Start: a
End: f
Path: a->c->f
Cost: 11

#After removal of "c"
Start: a
End: f
Path: a->f
Cost: 14
```

My full code is here:

```
from collections import deque
import sys

INFINITY = float("inf")

class Router():
    def __init__(self, node, graph):
        self.node = node
        self.graph = graph

    def get_path(self, node):
        path, cost = self.find_path(self.node, node, self.graph)
        print("Start: {}".format(self.node))
        print("End: {}".format(node))
        print("Path: {}".format("->".join(path)))
        print("Cost: {}\n".format(int(cost)))

    def find_path(self, start, end, graph):
        unvisited = graph.nodes.copy()
        distance_from_start = {node: (0 if node == start else INFINITY) for node in graph.nodes}
        previous = {node: None for node in graph.nodes}

        while unvisited:
            current = min(unvisited, key=lambda node: distance_from_start[node])
            unvisited.remove(current)

            if distance_from_start[current] == INFINITY:
                break

            for nearest, distance in graph.adjacency_list[current]:
                new_path = distance_from_start[current] + distance
                if new_path < distance_from_start[nearest]:
                    distance_from_start[nearest] = new_path
                    previous[nearest] = current

            if current == end:
                break

        path = deque()
        current = end
        while previous[current] is not None:
            path.appendleft(current)
            current = previous[current]
        path.appendleft(start)

        return path, distance_from_start[end]
        
class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph_edges = []
        self.nodes = set()
        self.adjacency_list = {}

    def add_edge(self, frm, to, cost=0):
        self.graph_edges.append((frm, to, float(cost)))

        for edge in self.graph_edges:
            self.nodes.update([edge[0], edge[1]])

        self.adjacency_list = {node: set() for node in self.nodes}
        for edge in self.graph_edges:
            self.adjacency_list[edge[0]].add((edge[1], edge[2]))

    def remove_edge(self, node):
        if node in self.nodes:
            self.nodes.remove(node)
            #print(self.nodes)
        for nodeval in self.adjacency_list.copy():
            if node in self.adjacency_list:
                print(self.adjacency_list.values())
                del self.adjacency_list[node]
                #print(self.adjacency_list) 
        for check in self.graph_edges.copy():
            if node in list(check):
                self.graph_edges.remove(check)
                #print(ch)
        for k,v in self.adjacency_list.items():
            for a in v:
                print(type(v))
                if node == a[0]:
                    del self.adjacency_list[node]
                    #print(self.adjacency_list[node])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = Graph()
    g2 = Graph()

    g.add_edge("a", "b", 7)
    g.add_edge("a", "c", 9)
    g.add_edge("a", "f", 14)
    g.add_edge("b", "c", 10)
    g.add_edge("b", "d", 15)
    g.add_edge("c", "d", 11)
    g.add_edge("c", "f", 2)
    g.add_edge("d", "e", 6)
    g.add_edge("e", "f", 9)

    g2.add_edge("x", "y", 7)
    g2.add_edge("x", "w", 9)
    g2.add_edge("x", "d", 14)
    g2.add_edge("y", "w", 10)
    g2.add_edge("y", "e", 15)
    g2.add_edge("w", "d", 11)
    g2.add_edge("w", "z", 2)
    g2.add_edge("d", "e", 6)
    g2.add_edge("e", "z", 9)

    router2 = Router("x", g2)
    router = Router("a", g)

    #print("Edges: {}\n".format(g.graph_edges))
    #print("Nodes: {}\n".format(g.nodes))
    #print("Adj List: {}\n".format(g.adjacency_list))
    router.get_path("f")
    #print(g.graph_edges)
    #print(g.adjacency_list)
    g.remove_edge("c")
    print(g.graph_edges)
    print(g.adjacency_list)
    print(g.nodes)
    #router.get_path("f")
    router2.get_path("e")
    node = "a"
    test = g.nodes.copy()
    adjtest = g.adjacency_list.copy()
    edgetest = g.graph_edges.copy()
    
    
    #if node in test:
        #test.remove(node)
        #print(test)
    #for nodeval in adjtest.copy().values():
        #if node in adjtest:
            #del adjtest[node]
            #print(adjtest)
    #for check in edgetest.copy():
        #if node in check:
            #edgetest.remove(check)
                #list_rem = list(check)
                #list_rem.clear()
                #check = tuple(list_rem)
            #print(check)
                #print(edgetest)
                #self.graph_edges.remove[node]
```

adjacency.list for graph g

```
{'c': {('d', 11.0), ('a', 9.0), ('f', 2.0)}, 'b': {('d', 15.0), ('c', 10.0)}, 'a': {('b', 7.0), ('c', 9.0), ('f', 14.0)}, 'f': set(), 'e': {('f', 9.0)}, 'd': {('e', 6.0)}}
```

Comment: can you explain last three lines of `add_edge`? They don't seem to make sense

Comment: @Marat Hi yes, so the first line creates a dictionary with a key of one of the possible nodes which is taken from the list of nodes(self.nodes), the value is a set(). The 2nd line identifies the info within each added route by grabbing the from, to and cost of each. In part 3, to and cost are updated to the set of each node it shares a connection with. I'll put a snippet of what it outputs if that may be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by clearing the data within each area except for the graph_edges and removed the necessary values I then recreated each one again by adding the data for graph_edges.

Here it is:

```
def remove_edge(self, node):
        for check in self.graph_edges.copy():
            if node in list(check):
                self.graph_edges.remove(check)

        self.nodes = set()
        self.adjacency_list = {}
        for edge in self.graph_edges:
            self.nodes.update([edge[0], edge[1]])

        self.adjacency_list = {node: set() for node in self.nodes}
        for edge in self.graph_edges:
            self.adjacency_list[edge[0]].add((edge[1], edge[2]))
```